# Jquery validate a limited non-repeating characterset

Tags: jquery, validation

How can I validate a user input using Jquery Validate to a limited character set, and then with those characters non-repeating?

The acceptable data entry must be:

1. Exactly seven characters long
2. Uppercase
3. Use only the characters "23456789FHLMQRSWXY"
4. No single character can be used more than once

I have the following code validating correctly using Jquery Validate:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .upper {text-transform:uppercase;}
</style>
```

and

```
<input type="text" name="referrer" maxlength="7" class="required upper" minlength="7" size="8" />
```

But I need to complete 3. & 4. to ensure that the user can only enter one of the following limited characterset that they are non repeating.

Thanks

Comment: _"I have the following code validating correctly using Jquery Validate"_ Isn't that CSS?

Comment: Ah yes - let me explain better! I am doing points 1 & 2 in CSS but the JQuery validate is working on all the other fields on the form (not shown here), my point being that JQuery Validate is installed and working.